# Serve a subset of OpenStreetMap as a WMS from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am trying to develop an application which should serve a small subset of OSM as a WMS for only my study area. I need it to be able to load higher-resolution tiles as the user zooms in.

I'm feeling a little lost right now. I can publish a WMS of a GeoTIFF in GeoServer. My first attempt was to save a QGIS project as a GeoTIFF, but obviously this is of course just a static image, so the resolution degrades when you zoom into it.

I download the "QTiles" plugin, which does a good job of generating a directory structure full of tiles, and so I am wondering, can I can simply somehow load this directory structure as a data source to GeoServer, and have it handle serving these tiles automatically?

My last-resort is to write a python script which will sew together the highest-resolution tiles into one contiguous image and just use this as the WMS data source, but I feel like this will probably not run optimally.

GeoServer version is 2.7.1.1

Comment: Which GeoServer version/release are you using?

Comment: Do geoserver is mandatory or other open source server GIS suits you?

Comment: @hannbroo: I updated the question

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov: Yes, Geoserver is mandatory.

Comment: step 1 - upgrade to geoserver 2.13.x or 2.14.x

Comment: @IanTurton Does the newer version come with this functionality already?

Comment: lots of new functionality, security fixes and support :-)

Comment: @IanTurton So is there a more direct way of serving a directory of tiles in 2.14.x or is MBTiles the way to go?

Comment: 2.14 will allow you to use a remote WMTS service as a wms/wmts layer - you need to import your OSM download and style it otherwise

Comment: @IanTurton So, if I am understanding this properly, I can have Geoserver build a local WMS data store from a remote WMS, like cloning it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86872/discussion-between-ian-turton-and-1saac).

Comment: geoserver can "serve" tiles